# WordPress | Sortby & filter - Archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

My code:

```
<?php
$the_key = 'upsidedate';  // The meta key to sort on
$args = array(
   'meta_key' => $the_key,
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC',
);
global $wp_query;
query_posts(
    array_merge(
        $wp_query->query,
        $args
    )
);
?>
<?php 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ;

get_template_part('post', 'archive');
endwhile;

else :
    get_template_part('post', 'noresults');
endif; 

get_template_part('navigation');
?>
```

What is doing now? its order by the custom field "upsidedate".

I want to order by the custom field "upsidedate" **and** filter by the custom field "done", I mean only if the value on "done" is "no" - it will show the post on archive.

Should be something like that:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'done', 'meta_value' => 'no' ) );
```

But I cant use meta_key twice.
How can I do that?

Comment: First of all, you cannot sort this way natively. You need get all posts with the required custom fields and then use `usort` to sort the results. Secondly, never use `query_posts`, it breaks pagination and the main query, so it is of no use calling the global `$wp_query` if you are going to break it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
$the_key = 'upsidedate';
query_posts(array(
        'meta_key' => $the_key,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'done',
                'value' => 'no',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    ));

 // For test only. Please comment it in production
 echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; die;
 // My query will be:

# SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  
#   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  
#   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (
#   wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'upsidedate'
#   AND
#   (
#     ( mt1.meta_key = 'done' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'no' )
#   )
# ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
#   GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
#   ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC LIMIT 0, 10
 // End test only
    wp_reset_query();
```

You can check again by command:

---

Updated:

```
$the_key = 'upsidedate';
query_posts(array(
        'meta_key' => $the_key,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'done',
                'value' => 'no',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    ));

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ;
    get_template_part('post', 'archive');
endwhile;

else :
    get_template_part('post', 'noresults');
endif;

get_template_part('navigation');

wp_reset_query();
```

If it still not work I think maybe you have some custom hook change the query of WP. This code will run property on a fresh WP install.

Hope that useful for someone!

Comment: No errors, but now the sort is upside (I mean its not 1,2,3 - its 3,2,1) and its still show me the post with another values on "done" custom field.

Comment: What about echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; Please see my update query and compare with your. If it is different check your hook such as "posts_where", "posts_join". If it is the same please check make sure the post has meta_key "done" and "upsidedate". Please see my update debug query

Comment: Now its fine. thank you! by the way.. its cannot be 'value' => 'no', its have to be $donevalue = 'no'; and than 'value' => $donevalue,